# jpype._core.JVMNotRunning: Java Virtual Machine is not running

Tags: python-3.x, dagster

> ```
> jpype._core.JVMNotRunning: Java Virtual Machine is not running
> /././lib/python3.10/site-packages/dagster/_core/workspace/context.py:610:
> ```
>
> UserWarning: Error loading repository location
> etl:jpype._core.JVMNotRunning: Java Virtual Machine is not running

my code is

```
import jpype
jpype.startJVM(jpype.getDefaultJVMPath(), "-ea")
try:
jpype.addClassPath("/../../Hapi.jar")
YourJavaClass = jpype.JClass("com.netspective.hl7v2.HL7V2Parser")
java_instance = YourJavaClass()
result = java_instance.messageToJsonprocess('MSH|^~\&|SENDING_APP|SENDING_FACILITY|RECEIVING_APP|RECEIVING_FACILITY|202110171200||ADT^A01|123456789|P|2.3','processed_2.3_ECMC_0be3f24a-c56c-4c.hl7')
finally:
jpype.shutdownJVM()
```

when i was run this code code as python file it works.but when i implement this code in dagster it shows the error that i given above.please fix this error.